# Is that possible to install unsigned firmware on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, cydia, firmware

I wanted to install the 9.0.2 firmware on my idevices, but it's no more signed by Apple, so I can't install any firmware below 9.1.

Is there any way to bypass that ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. Apple always allows any app which must be apple certified. If you want to use in your iphone/ipad, you can go for jailbreak. I think jailbreaking your ios devices will let you use un-certified apps. I don't know about mac os.

Comment: I am already jailbreaken, in iOS 8.1.1, but I wanted to upgrade in 9.0.2 (to keep the jailbreak), but itunes don't let me do this... :/
I was wondering if there is any solution to bypass Apple verification ?

Comment: there is no solution?!

Answer (score 1):

There are some complicated ways to achieve that. But it's not supported by
Apple and it's quite risky. You can find some videos on youtube for downgrading to unsigned ios version like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxf7Rlb0nSA

Answer (score 0):

No Apple has the keys to the software that they sign and unsigned which means only the developers of apple with the keys can downgrade! And if you dont have the keys then no it is not possible (: